# Wordpress comment pagination : newest comments on first page

Tags: comments, pagination

I use Wordpress commment pagination as follows:

- paginated comments
- comments displayed with the newest comments at the top of each page
- 50 comments on each page
- first page displayed by default

The problem is that I am trying to achieve YouTube like comments such as - newest comments on first page, first page being displayed by default, then older comments in order on page 2, 3 etc

The problem is that Wordpress comments are structured in such way,that I cannot achieve this by changing the "Discussion" settings.

I have tried different options, such as extending the Walker's paged_walk() function, or to reverse the comments, or even pulling the comments with a MySQL query and using paginate_link() - but can't seem to be able to achieve this type of comments hierarchy.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

**Solution:**

I have found a solution as follows:

- into functions.php I have inserted a custom function that sorts the comments by date (newest comments first) by using an associative array sorting as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)
- into the Wordpress settings I changed the following at Settings -> Discussion *Comments should be displayed with the  comments at the top of each page*

So now my comments are being displayed newest first (at top) with page numbering starting from 1.

The only issue that I see, is that when posting a comment the user is redirected for some reason to the last page of comments.

Comment: Please add your solution as real answer, then mark the question as _answered._ If you don’t … I’ll do it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution as follows:

into functions.php I have inserted a custom function that sorts the comments by date (newest comments first) by using an associative array sorting as can be seen here
into the Wordpress settings I changed the following at Settings -> Discussion Comments should be displayed with the comments at the top of each page

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to arrange your comments by most recent is to add this to your functions.php file:

```
if (!function_exists('custom_reverse_comments')) {
    function custom_reverse_comments($comments) {
        return array_reverse($comments);
    }   
}
add_filter ('comments_array', 'custom_reverse_comments');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I used something similar in my solution to this, please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('pre_get_comments', function($query){
    if ( !is_admin()) {
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
    }
});
```

and set sorting in backend to oldest comments first in settings